# High Temperatures Compaq Presario C700, CPU Fan Speed problem

Tags: overheating, temperature, fancontrol, presario

I've been having some problems with Fan speed with my Compaq Presario C700 Laptops (I've got 3 Laptops, all with the same problem).

I install Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS but the CPU fan always works at the minimum Speed, so after a while the core hit 80°C+ temperatures and the laptops just showdown/close.

I tried `lm-sensors` but still no changes at fan speed.

Does anyone know what can I do? 
Do I need to install some other driver or something?

I really don't bother about the noise, I just want the laptops to work and keep them away from heat damage.

Thank you

```
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!

    (driver `coretemp')
```

-

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:       +73.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Comment: Hi how do you get the temperature? I would like to know how. Also, did you ever over-clock the computers? It might be the problem.

Comment: I think the high temp should be 85 and not 100.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps installing thermald (if it's not already being used) would be helpful to control thermal over-runs. Use:

```
sudo apt-get install thermald
```

..and see if that controls the system.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, I'd check that you have the latest BIOS installed (F.35 Rev. A).

**Second**, I'd install `thermald`...

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install thermald

It comes with a default `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml` file that will control most computers, but may need to be customized for some computers. See `man thermal-conf.xml` for some details and examples.

After installing thermald, I'd stop the `thermald` process, and run it manually as `sudo thermald --no-daemon` to watch its actions in real time. This real time info can be used to create your own customized thermal-conf.xml file. See `man thermald` for more information.

**Third**, older laptops such as yours get clogged with dust, and the processor thermal paste needs refreshing. The easist thing to do is to open the laptop and blow out the dust that settles in the fan assembly, and around the processor and various chips. More difficult is to remove the thermal heat pipe that's mounted on top of the processor chip and replace the thermal paste.

Comment: @BillMetallinos status please?